# How can I make divs "pin" to spots in the background?

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming and I am in a group trying to make a website that has clickable planets that will take the user to the wikipedia page. However, when I view the website on my computer with a larger screen, the background image with the planets scales, but the divs stay put. Can anyone help?

```
<div class="planetClickArea" id="mercury"
onclick="window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)');">  
</div>

#mercury {
left:271px;
top: 296px;
height: 55px;
width: 55px;
}
.planetClickArea {
border:2px solid white;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
}
body {
max-height:1080px;
min-height:200px;
max-width:1920px;
min-width:200px;
background-image:url("img/solar_system_menu.jpg"); 

background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 


}
```

Comment: Use relative units `%`, `em`, `rem`, `vh`, `vw`, etc instead of `px` (pixel) values if you want those elements to scale. Pixels are hard values that won't scale.

Comment: you could also use jquery to calculate where you want to place your pins.